# How to calculate hitrate of shared buffer in postgresql, using TPC-C workload?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, benchmark

I use TPC-C(benchmarksql 4.0) to test postgres. I set up `warehousenum=1000`, the whole database is about `100GB`, and I set `shared_buffers=10GB` in `postgresql.conf`. I also set `terminalWarehouseFixed=false` to change the  warehouse, and I run the benchmark for `20mins`.
But when I calculate the hitrate with the sql below, I got a very high hitrate, that was strange. I also print the workload of benchmarksql, it did choose warehouse, district, customer at random. And I modified postgres to output the access times of blocks of the table file, though it is skewed, but it can't cause that high hit rate in shared buffer.

```
with 
all_tables as
(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  'all'::text as table_name, 
        sum( (coalesce(heap_blks_read,0) + coalesce(idx_blks_read,0) + coalesce(toast_blks_read,0) + coalesce(tidx_blks_read,0)) ) as from_disk, 
        sum( (coalesce(heap_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(idx_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(toast_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(tidx_blks_hit,0))  ) as from_cache    
    FROM    pg_statio_USER_tables  --> change to pg_statio_USER_tables if you want to check only user tables (excluding postgres's own tables)
    ) a
WHERE   (from_disk + from_cache) > 0 -- discard tables without hits
),
tables as 
(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  relname as table_name, 
        ( (coalesce(heap_blks_read,0) + coalesce(idx_blks_read,0) + coalesce(toast_blks_read,0) + coalesce(tidx_blks_read,0)) ) as from_disk, 
        ( (coalesce(heap_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(idx_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(toast_blks_hit,0)  + coalesce(tidx_blks_hit,0))  ) as from_cache    
    FROM    pg_statio_USER_tables --> change to pg_statio_USER_tables if you want to check only user tables (excluding postgres's own tables)
    ) a
WHERE   (from_disk + from_cache) > 0 -- discard tables without hits
)
SELECT  table_name as "table name",
    from_disk as "disk hits",
    round((from_disk::numeric / (from_disk + from_cache)::numeric)*100.0,2) as "% disk hits",
    round((from_cache::numeric / (from_disk + from_cache)::numeric)*100.0,2) as "% cache hits",
    (from_disk + from_cache) as "total hits"
FROM    (SELECT * FROM all_tables UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tables) a
ORDER   BY (case when table_name = 'all' then 0 else 1 end), from_disk desc;
```

[image]

Comment: Just look at the `pg_stat_database` columns `blks_read` and `blks_hit`.

Comment: Without knowing what you expect and why you expect it, what can we tell you?

Comment: Sorry, my expression may not be very clear. Why is the hit ratio so high when the ratio of shared buffer to database is one to ten?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe the result is 94%, also very high, almost every access to the table can hit in shared buffer, why? Does it mean that tpc-c is a very skew workload, only 10% of the database is accessed frequently?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't know TPC-C.